# github Readme - reference issue

Tags: github, markdown

How can I reference (insert a relative link to) an issue in my github Readme.md?

I found the following document [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown) where it is described how to reference to an issue in a commit, but not in the readme.

E.g. if the Issue is: https://github.com/user/project/issues/5 how can I set a link to it in my readme without using absolute links?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is not ([officially](https://help.github.com/articles/about-readmes/#relative-links-and-image-paths-in-readme-files)) possible. GitHub Flavored Markdown is not used for rendering markdown files in your repo, it is used only for issues and comments. So, readme files are rendered using normal markdown, and no autolinking will happen for issues, SHAs and similar constructs.

Comment: From: https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/
"You can use Markdown most places around GitHub:" .. "Files with the .md or .markdown extension"

Not being able to link to git commits, or issues, as described in that guide creates extra, unnecessary work.

Answer (score 78):

There's a pretty ugly way of doing something like that *if you only want to refer to issues from the same repo*, which as of 2015-04-29 works:

```
see also [#3](/../../issues/3)
```

Comment: Nice use of [GitHub's relative links](https://github.com/blog/1395-relative-links-in-markup-files) ;)

Comment: also, this works only from within a branch name _without_ slashes

Comment: Still works but [GitHub's relative links](https://github.com/blog/1395-relative-links-in-markup-files) says nowhere that this is allowed, and as most `..` path traversals have security implications, I'd expect Github to block this sooner or later.  I'm staying with absolute links.

Comment: Only problem with this method is that the links don't work in forked versions.

Comment: @MichaelDimmitt I was imagining a relative link in a markdown file contained in the repo - the main readme, contribution.md, etc.

Comment: @Mottie, you can put a relative link on a markdown file on a forked repository, you just need to refer to the original repository in the relative link by moving further back and then on the correct user and correct branch. My previous comment did not put the code correctly, so I understand the confusion. ```[#4](../../../../UserName/RepoName/issues/4)```

Comment: You could just do `[#3](/user/repo/issue/3)` so you don't have to do the `/../..`

Answer (score 53):

This is not strictly the solution to your question, but maybe the solution to your problem.

I too wanted to avoid to add absolute URLs to links in my CHANGELOG, because it would make the lines so long and unreadable.

But when using reference style links, it's not too bad:

```
* [feature] Add an awesome feature ([#33][i33])
* [bug] Finally fixed this stupid bug ([#19][i19])

[i19]: https://github.com/user/repo/issues/19
[i33]: https://github.com/user/repo/issues/33
```

One of the big advantages is that it also works outside of Github.

Comment: That works great, thanks!  As you mentioned, this works well outside of Github, which is perfect for npm (Node) packages.