# How to get a commit SHA to link to Github commit in markdown file

Tags: github

In GitHub a commit SHA in an issue or comment is automatically hyperlinked to the commit when it renders on the browser, however in a markdown file (e.g `Changelog.md`) this does not happen ([an example](https://github.com/nanoporetech/dorado/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)). Is there a way to get this same behaviour in markdown files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [autolinked references](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/autolinked-references-and-urls) are not supported in regular md files.

This [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539687/github-readme-reference-issue) talks about using absolute and relative references such as:

- `[<hash>](https://github.com/user/project/commit/<hash>)`
- `[<hash>](/../../commit/<hash>)`